# Hi there, is there a problem with dedent in idle with python 3.8.1

Tags: python, python-idle

I'm just trying to dedent a very simple print line after a simple loop and the control [ technique is not working. Please forgive me for asking a stupid question but I just can't figure this out and I am just starting on this Python journey. Thanks!

```
magics = ["a", "b", "c"]
for magic in magics:
    print (f "hello {magic})
print f("This is weird")
```

so - the `print f("this is weird")` piece won't dedent if I select the text and then try to use ctrl [. The print command goes to the very left side and then gives me a syntax error.

Again, sorry for the stupid question...but thanks!

Comment: of course, each of these parts is on a new line...and properly indented except for the 'this is weird' print portion...

Comment: `print(f"hello {magic}")` no spaces!!!. And you need closing `"`.

Comment: absolutely you are right...but even when I do have the proper " and spaces, I still can't dedent that final print "this is weird" that isn't in the loop... :(

Comment: What do you mean? just move it 4 spaces to the right. The last line is not valid syntax, why would it be in a different format than the line above? and note you don't need `f` there anyway.

Comment: I'm not explaining this well...sorry...I want the last line "this is weird" to print after I'm out of the loop. In order to do that, I have to dedent that print line. The idle help says that to dedent something, I select the text, then press ctrl [ and that should dedent it. This doesn't seem to work and I wondered why...and I tried moving it to the right using backspace (4 spaces) also and this didn't work either...

Comment: sorry, tried moving it to the left, using backspace...

Comment: I don't know about using ctrl for indentation, but if you want `This is weird` to be printed after the loop you don't need to indent it, just fix the syntax. You are using the `f` wrong, it should be just like the first print. And you don't need it there anyway.

Comment: so, when I don't dedent it, (and I have fixed up the syntax and have tried both with the f and without, as you suggested), the 'this is weird' statement prints for each of  hello a, hello b and hello c. So I have to dedent to get just one 'this is weird' statement at the end. But I can't seem to do it. If I try control [ or try to backspace 4 spaces, the print  ("this is weird") does not dedent by 4 spaces but instead, goes to the very edge of the shell. Then when I try to run it like that, it gives me a syntax error. And THANK YOU, Guy, for trying to help me...I'm just learning...

Comment: Did you add the closing `"` to `print(f"hello {magic}")`?

Comment: yes: I did fix up that syntax- I just can't make that last print dedent for love nor money...

Comment: Than I don't understand the problem, please update your question with the current code, and expected and actual output.

Comment: Do you mean you want `"This is weird"` to be printed not in the same line as `"hello {magic}"`?

Comment: The way the last line is displayed above, it is already dedented.